# Variable Multithread Access - Corruption

Tags: swift, multithreading, queue, dispatch

**In a nutshell:**

I have one counter variable that is accessed from many threads. Although I've implemented multi-thread read/write protections, the variable seems to still -in an inconsistent way- get written to simultaneously, leading to incorrect results from the counter.

**Getting into the weeds:**

I'm using a "for loop" that triggers roughly 100 URL requests in the background, each in its “DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async” queue.

These processes are async, once they finish they update a “counter” variable. This variable is supposed to be multi-thread protected, meaning it’s always accessed from one thread and it’s accessed syncronously. However, something is wrong, from time to time the variable will be accessed simultaneously by two threads leading to the counter not updating correctly. Here's an example, lets imagine we have 5 URLs to fetch:

We start with the Counter variable at 5.

1 URL Request Finishes -> Counter = 4

2 URL Request Finishes -> Counter = 3

3 URL Request Finishes -> Counter = 2

4 URL Request Finishes (and for some reason – I assume variable is accessed at the same time) -> Counter 2

5 URL Request Finishes -> Counter = 1

As you can see, this leads to the counter being 1, instead of 0, which then affects other parts of the code. This error happens inconsistently.

Here is the multi-thread protection I use for the counter variable:

1. Dedicated Global Queue

> //Background queue to syncronize data access fileprivate let
>   globalBackgroundSyncronizeDataQueue = DispatchQueue(label:
>   "globalBackgroundSyncronizeSharedData")

2. Variable is always accessed via accessor:

> ```
> var numberOfFeedsToFetch_Value: Int = 0
> var numberOfFeedsToFetch: Int {
>     set (newValue) {
>         globalBackgroundSyncronizeDataQueue.sync()  {
>             self.numberOfFeedsToFetch_Value = newValue
>         }
>     }
>     get {
>         return globalBackgroundSyncronizeDataQueue.sync {
>             numberOfFeedsToFetch_Value
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I assume I may be missing something but I've used profiling and all seems to be good, also checked the documentation and I seem to be doing what they recommend. Really appreciate your help.

Thanks!!

Comment: How about using locking mechanism `NSLock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Apple Forums:https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/322332#322332:

> The individual accessors are thread safe, but an increment operation
>   isn't atomic given how you've written the code.  That is, while one
>   thread is getting or setting the value, no other threads can also be
>   getting or setting the value.  However, there's nothing preventing
>   thread A from reading the current value (say, 2), thread B reading the
>   same current value (2), each thread adding one to this value in their
>   private temporary, and then each thread writing their incremented
>   value (3 for both threads) to the property.  So, two threads
>   incremented but the property did not go from 2 to 4; it only went from
>   2 to 3.   You need to do the whole increment operation (get, increment
>   the private value, set) in an atomic way such that no other thread can
>   read or write the property while it's in progress.